# CakePHP: managing user capabilities in wordpress way

Tags: cakephp, user-management, capability

I Googled for this for over 3 hours but didn't find anything helpful. Is there any `CakePHP` plugin that allows managing user roles and capabilities without building `ACL`, the wordpress way?

Why built-in CakePHP ACL does not meet my needs:

- it's kind of overkill for not very big applications
- Keep updating ACOS can be pain.
- you can't use version control to track roles and capabilities changes

What I would like new plugin to be:

- in `AppController` or somewhere else you can define array of supplied capabilities. I do not need them to be dynamic, though in wordpress that was done even without database. I don't even think capabilities should match controller methods (but maybe I am not right there)
- when initializing roles, you can set which capabilities are true for that role
- in view file, you can check if current user has the capability, f.e., to edit slug field, and if yes, show this field.

I am really not an authentication specialist and may sound like an ordinary wordpress fan, but to my point of view wordpress system of user management is really efficient and could be implemented in CakePHP.

Comment: A bit off topic, but to keep ACO easily synchronized with app actions, you could use this plugin: http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0

Comment: Yes, thanks. I'll have to use it if I find no other solution.

Comment: Have you considered building this plugin yourself? I think I'm about to embark on said project myself.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the CakeDC users plugin which will do what you want.

https://github.com/cakedc/users

Be sure to check the 2.0 branch if you are using CakePHP 2.x

Comment: I read plugin's documentation and here what it says: "Simple roles management". This is not what I am looking for. I need roles and **capabilities** management.

Comment: That's something you can build on very simply.

Comment: Yes. It's as close as I know. Building role management or capability management is really outside the scope of a plugin, so you'll struggle to find one which includes such project specific code.